# Draw a line on specific data value on cartesian chart in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, charts, draw

Is there a way to draw a line on a graph (or at least get the position) on specific date?

I have a graph where X is Date data, I want to draw a line with a text on each Year and each 3 months as reference, not part of the graph series.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably already found your answer but for posterity, Here is the [tutorial](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_eventsandeffects_13.html#298038).